# how to slowly transform scale with css?

Tags: css, transform, scale

I currently have it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9DGb2/

But for some reason if I change the css to this:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
div:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05) slow;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) slow;
    -o-transform: scale(1.05) slow;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05) slow;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) slow;
    transform: scale(1.05) slow;
}
```

It wont work.

So I am guessing it cant be done this way?

Comment: You need to learn about `transition`.

Comment: What makes you think you can assign a speed to CSS transformations? Are you maybe thinking about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 30):

You need to add a `transition`

```
-webkit-transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9DGb2/3/)

For more information please consult: [Using CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: You should add the transition to the div itself, this way the transition goes in both ways (hovering and un-hovering). It's prettier

Comment: @singe31 very true, he didn't specify that he wanted it both ways so I assumed not, I updated my JSFiddle to reflect that, MrLars take note of singe31's comment!

Answer (score 10):

transition in other browser

```
div:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);

    -webkit-transition: transform 1.05s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:transform 1.05s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:transform 1.05s ease-in-out;
}
```